# Creating an array in a nested column in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following DF schema:

```
|—categories: array (nullable = true)
|     |—element: struct (containsNull = true)
|     |      |-- children: array (nullable = true)
|     |      |     |-- element: string
|     |      |-- id: Long (nullable = true)
|     |      |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to parse it to the following schema:

```
|—categories: array (nullable = true)
|     |—element: struct (containsNull = true)
|     |      |-- children: array (nullable = true)
|     |      |     |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|     |      |            |— id: Long (nullable = true)
|     |      |            |-- name: string (nulLable = true)
|     |      |-- id: Long (nullable = true)
|     |      |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Basically I need to cast the `element` column to `StructType` and add `id` and `name` columns. I’ve tried to that using:

```
df.withColumn(‘categories’, F.expr(‘transform(categories, x -> struct(x.id, x.name))’))
```

When I use the above code I get the following schema:

```
|—categories: array (nullable = true)
|     |—element: struct (containsNull = true)
|     |  |-— id: Long (nullable = true)
|     |  |-- name: string (nulLable = true)
```

How can I achieve my desired schema?

Comment: Please show the sample data.  Your original `children` is array of "string".  We need to know how it looks like to know how to extract.

Comment: @Emma, the problem is, this is a Delta DF and my historical data has the desired schema. When there is no data in the array, spark infers it as a string, when it has data it has the desired schema (struct instead array). Basically it needs to be casted as an empty struct.

Comment: okay. In that case, can you can pass schema while reading to enforce the schema?  also, no data meaning null or empty string?

Comment: I enforced the schema on `spark.read…` and it worked. Thanks @Emma. Can you post it as answer please? So I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing schema while reading to enforce it if you have a fixed schema.

```
schema = StructType(...)

df = spark.read.schema(schema)...
```

This will make sure those null values to be casted to the schema that you specified.